# PHP Facebook SDK / Graph API - How do I include symbols, eg ©, in a wall post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How do I post symbols (eg. ©) in a wall post using the graph api? Html entities (eg. &copy;) aren't parsed in facebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All large text fields are utf-8, use the actual character used to represent it which is U+00A9

If you have HTML entities you can decode with html_entity_decode()

$utf8_text = html_entity_decode("test © foo", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

Comment: +1, example: `$facebook->api('/USER_ID/feed', 'post', array('message'=>utf8_encode('all rights reserved ©')));`

Comment: @ifaour Thanks! I couldn't find anything on google about this

Comment: @JohnHimmelman, you are welcome...Facebook employees should learn to provide some code from time to time ;-) the SO community encourage this!

Comment: you don't need to utf8_encode() anything that is already utf8 encoded. Typing in the copyright character verbatim would do this.

If you really want to change htmlentities back to unicode use: 

$utf8_text = html_entity_decode("test &copy; foo", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");