# Bad character when publish

Tags: facebook, special-characters, publish

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Facebook SDK / Graph API - How do I include symbols, eg ©, in a wall post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796603/php-facebook-sdk-graph-api-how-do-i-include-symbols-eg-in-a-wall-post)

this is my application and with this I can share on my wall, but i think there are some problems with some character set for example this letter: ù è ì

This is the admin panel..

http://onlyimagination.com/ADMIN.jpg

And this is AFTER I do the wall post command.

http://onlyimagination.com/share.jpg

How i can fix this issue of the character in my application?

Comment: Use UTF-8 at all times.<br />
Show your code for a more specific answer.

Comment: Hi, is already set to UTF-8 look my settings.. http://onlyimagination.com/dream.jpg

Comment: Show us the code that get it posted, without it it's we can only blindly guess...

Comment: We need to see the actual code where you do the posting

Comment: ok this is the code of my page please help me: onlyimagination.com/admin.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML encoding for the special characters, it looks like the second page needs to decode these for the user (instead of displaying as literal text).  If this is facebook you'll need to check the docs.

Comment: ok this is the code of my page please help me: onlyimagination.com/admin.pdf